# adf: Using radio button in af:table for single row selection

Tags: oracle-adf

This is not exactly an question, better to say - it's an answer with a little question: is there a better sollution? :)

Suppose you have a grid which contains some rows.

In each row you want to put a radio button, and only one radio button can be selected in the grid (each row has one radio button). 
This radio button should be used not only to display selected row, but also to select a row by clicking radio button.
Selection is based on a table's field, which contains 1 for selected and 0 or  null for all other rows.

Here is a short guide of achieving it:

1. (the obvious part)

add a column with a radiobutton:

```
<af:column headerText="#{bindings.DocsignersliteView2.hints.Isactual.label}"
           id="c14" align="center">
     <af:selectBooleanRadio label="Label 1"
                            id="sbr1"
                            value="#{row.Isactual}"
                            group="Isactual"                                
                            autoSubmit="true">
     </af:selectBooleanRadio>
</af:column>
```

where Isactual - is the field in the table, which containts 1 for selected item and null for all others

Method onActual should be implemened to change values of the field Isactual in the table.

2. it appears to not work. Now it shows an actual row, but doesn't work when I select another radio button. 
   Naturally I tried to create ValueChangeListener, but never succeded - it didn't work correctly.
   Ok, let's try to invert "onClickListener", as selectBooleanRadio doesn't posess such an attribute:

let's add clientlistener, javascript and server listener:

```
        <af:resource type="javascript">
          function onClickRadio(actionEvent) {
              var comp = actionEvent.getSource();
              AdfCustomEvent.queue(comp, "IsactualClickEvent", 
                                   {},
                                   true);
              actionEvent.cancel();
          }
        </af:resource>

    <af:selectBooleanRadio label="Label 1"
                           id="sbr1"
                           value="#{row.Isactual}"
                           group="Isactual"
                           autoSubmit="true">
            <af:clientListener type="click" method="onClickRadio"/>
        <af:serverListener type="IsactualClickEvent"
                           method="#{viewScope.signerBean.onActual}"/>
    </af:selectBooleanRadio>
```

3. it almost works, but there is one more 'tiny' detail: a field with 1 and 0 values (or 1 and null) - is not exactly the same as boolean, so this selectBooleanRadio needs a converter.

So we should create a class implementing converter:

```
public class BooleanDecimalConverter implements Converter {
    public BooleanDecimalConverter() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uIComponent, String string) {
        if (string == null || string.isEmpty())
            return null;
        return "true".equals(string) ? BigDecimal.valueOf(1) : BigDecimal.valueOf(0);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uIComponent, Object object) {
        if (object == null)
            return null;
        String result;
        if (object instanceof Boolean){
            result = object.toString();
        }
        else if (object instanceof BigDecimal) {
            BigDecimal num = ((BigDecimal)object);
            result = num.compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(1)) == 0? "true" : "false";
        }
        else {
            result = "false";
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

then register the custom converter in the application's JSF configuration file (faces-config.xml):

```
<converter>
    <converter-id>custom.BooleanDecimalConverter</converter-id>
    <converter-class>common.utils.converters.BooleanDecimalConverter</converter-class>
</converter>
```

and at last we can add a converter attribute to af:selectBooleanRadio:

```
    <af:selectBooleanRadio label="Label 1"
                           id="sbr1"
                           value="#{row.Isactual}"
                           group="Isactual"
                           converter="custom.BooleanDecimalConverter"
                           autoSubmit="true">
            <af:clientListener type="click" method="onClickRadio"/>
        <af:serverListener type="IsactualClickEvent"
                           method="#{viewScope.signerBean.onActual}"/>
    </af:selectBooleanRadio>
```

What we have now:

A grid with rows, radio buttons show an "active" row and allow user to change "active" row immediately as he clicks the radio button.